# Permanent Data Sets

Tags: sas

If you create a permanent data set, will the formats and labels not transfer over? When I use `PROC PRINT`, all the labels and formats are applied correctly. But when I open up the actual data set I created, none of the labels and formats are applied. I also stored my formats into a catalog using **PROC FORMAT LIBRARY** and `OPTIONS FMTSEARCH`. So it should work because the formats are also permanent.

Comment: What do you mean by "open" the data set? Are you using a graphical interface, or interactive mode on a unix system?

Comment: @itzy: I am using SAS Universal Viewer to view the data set.

Comment: I haven't used that, but it sounds like the viewer doesn't display formats by default. Not much of an answer though...

Comment: @itzy: I see. So if I opened the data set as an excel file, the formats would probably show? In other words, it depends on the program you use to view the data set?

Comment: Do you have label and format statements in your Proc Print?

Comment: @CarolinaJay65: I have a label statement. All the format statements are in the data step.

Answer (score 1):

Are your formats user-defined?  If so you need to follow the below instructions to enable them in SAS Universal Viewer:

> You can apply SAS formats to or remove SAS formats from columns in the data set you are viewing. Right-click to select a cell in the column for which you want to change the format. In the menu that appears, check or uncheck Format. The Format option acts like a toggle.
>   In the window, you can supply user-defined formats. These formats need to be created in SAS, exported to an XML formats file, and then imported to SAS Universal Viewer where they can be used to format values.

(Taken from http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/univiewerug/63357/PDF/default/univiewerug.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Execute a [Proc Contents](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p084-27.pdf) or [Datasets](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/274-2011.pdf) on your data set to determine formats, labels (and other attributes).

```
Proc Contents data=yourlib.yourdata;
run;

Proc datasets library=yourlib;
 Contents data=yourdata details varnum memtype=data;
run;
quit;
```

It is helpful if you post your code.

Comment: I did a PROC CONTENTS already and just got the list of variables and the labels and format names.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to use the **PUT** statement instead of the format statement. Also had to use libname.data instead of just data for saving formats for new data sets.